# reg Query not working in for loop bat script

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, registry

Following is my code in .bat script

```
 FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG.EXE QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /V "Version"') DO SET IEVer=%%B
```

For this I am getting error

```
 'REG.EXE QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /V "Version"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have also tried

```
 FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('%systemRoot%\system32\REG QUERY  "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /V "Version"') DO SET IEVer=%%B
```

still getting the same error.

However on running

```
 D:\>REG.EXE QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /V "Version"
```

I get output

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
 Version    REG_SZ    9.11.9600.18378
```

This is happening only on one machine??? Any ideas??

Comment: What happens on that particular machine if you run the same batch file on the following key instead? `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it's working fine for me on windows 7 x64

```
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN ('REG.EXE QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /V "Version"') DO SET IEVer=%%B 
echo %iever% 
pause
```

the Echo is returning me: 9.11.9600.18426

- c:\Temp>SET IEVer=
- c:\Temp>SET IEVer=9.11.9600.18426
- c:\Temp>echo 9.11.9600.18426
- 9.11.9600.18426  Pause

Comment: For me it is working on all machines except one. The machine type is Windows 2012 R2. I am not able to debug why it is failing on this machine.

Comment: I just tested 2 different 2012 r2 computer and it also work fine, so the problem is really the computer and not the script.

Answer (score 0):

For BAT File:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3* skip=2" %%v in (`reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v "Version"`) do set iever=%%v
```

For CMD Tests:

```
@for /f "usebackq tokens=3* skip=2" %v in (`reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v "Version"`) do @echo %v
```

> Use param "**usebackq**" and back quotes for run an application inside "**for loop**"
>
> Change **tokens** and **skip** params if you will need.